# How to change CSS of blogger's first post only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs

I want to change the CSS of my blog's first post only ([digitalsorify](http://www.aakashstore.in)) so that it looks like [The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com) without using jquery.

Comment: You mean you want the first post to be full width? You aren't going to do that by modifying your css. Your html structure will need to be changed.

Comment: Exactly but rest of blog posts look as it is....CSS modifies only first post.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the title (with CSS):

```
.wrapfullpost:first-child {
    /* put first post style here */
}
```

Comment: thanx...this solve the problem but widget on the other side hides the content...how to manage this?

Comment: @zeeshanansari, add `z-index: 999` for your content.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
#content-wrapper { padding-top: 400px;}
.wrapfullpost:first-child { position: absolute;margin-top: -400px;}
```

This look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFWQA.png after my manipulation.

Comment: i did not down rated you....i'm not having sufficient reputation to do so...btw your code breaks on opening the post...

Comment: im not correct understand your comment :) to prevent changes in posts you need to change html.

Comment: you can put you #main-wrapper to another div on only main page, and change css only for this: <div class="someclass"><div id="main-wrapper"> {content here}</div></div> and then in css write something like this: .someclass .wrapfullpost:first-child { position: absolute;margin-top: -400px;}